# Magento2 - Extend Element\Template - Interceptor problem

Tags: magento2, template

I'm creating an extension that adds the function to switch tax view for customers. Because I need the same functions in multiple views I created a preference for Template:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" type="Silvan\TaxSwitcher\Template" />
</config>
```

And my Template class:

```
class Template extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /** @var \Silvan\TaxSwitcher\Model\Session */
    protected $session;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, Session $session, array $data)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    /**
     * showInclTax method
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function showInclTax()
    {
        return $this->session->getTaxState() === 'incl-tax';
    }

    /**
     * showExclTax method
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function showExclTax()
    {
        return $this->session->getTaxState() === 'incl-tax' ? false : true;
    }
```

This class is called correctly. But when I try to use my function in minicart.phtml in my theme I get this error:

```
Invalid method Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor::showInclTax(Array
(
)
)
```

The function showInclTax is not created in the Interceptor. How does this work? Why is it not created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preference do not change inheritance tree. So when you define preference, all classes inherited from template do not get your methods.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this. Can you advice another way to make the functions work?

Comment: Add  your block as child for Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar and use methods as $block->getChildBlock('block_alias')->showExclTax()

Comment: @KAndy how interface can call method not exist
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Downloadable/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Data/Samples.php#L116  getStoreTitle method not exist

Comment: @mrtuvn, Sample model extended from DataObject and have __call method, so you get data using method not form interface. But it bad practice and should be avoided

Comment: what benifits of interface? . I see alot of interfaces implemented by class in cores. Does it related to virtual type in dependency injection

Comment: @KAndy. Thank your response but i dont really understand how it can call method by __call without any field key? What really purposes of use interfaces. Any practices or article about this